# How the single JAR build on Windows and Linux be different?

Tags: java, linux, maven, hadoop

I'm building a single jar file to run it on Hadoop cluster. When I build the jar on Windows platform and then copy it to Hadoop machine it works fine but when I build the jar on Linux machine. It gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/hadoop-unjar7077828764688507370/META-INF/maven/com.google.guava (Is a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.unJar(RunJar.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.unJar(RunJar.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Extract of pom.xml is as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Skip the tests run. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Sources generation -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.ga.gachainmr.GAChainMR</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Let me know if you need any other files.

Comment: Compare the two files, either manually or using tools like "beyond compare". Do you run one of the files on the same computer you build it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding guava dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried this and it did work but, a new one "org.apache.commons" (is a directory) shows up and this time adding dependency didn't work. I think there is root cause to this problem and for that, I need to understand what is difference in building a jar on different platforms.